# ansi c realtime surface bitmap packing

Tags: c, bitmap, bit, ansi-c

I am interested in the question of how to pack pixels into a buffer in a certain specified format like RGB 565, RGB 888, BGR 888, RGBA 8888, immediately change the values of one pixel if necessary, and not convert all or part of the buffer?

Would it be good practice to edit a void* bitmap buffer into a specific format using different functions that handle different formats and a single pointer to them?
For example, I have four functions that fill the buffer in RGB888, RGBA8888, BGRA8888 and RGB565 formats, and if I have defined the RGB565 buffer format, I simply set the corresponding function to the pointer responsible for filling the buffer. Or is this bad and I need to look for another approach?

Comment: `switch(format) { case RGB565: uint16_t *pix = pixel_data; /* etc */ }`

Comment: Details here are sparse, and it is unclear what you are asking.   The functions shown seem to be prototypes of partially formed thoughts.  If they are actually defined somewhere, and part of a program you are writing, then please edit your post to show it in the form of a [mcve].  without that it will be difficult to know how to help.

Comment: You just say if the format is this do this, if the format is that do that, and so on.

Comment: @ryyker, this is a software render and I just got stuck at the moment of writing to the buffer.

Comment: Consider standardizing on a single internal format.  Perform conversions to other formats only on the fly, as needed, when you output the resulting images.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yes, but doesn't it reduce performance significantly because the update happens at least 60 times per second ?

Comment: You never said you were performing animation.  But even so, "reduces performance" is a straw man.  The question should be whether it is *too expensive*.  Maybe it is, and maybe it isn't.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the renderer should draw the user interface, and the system should display it on the screen. But on different systems, different bitmap formats and it seemed to me a good idea to draw immediately in the right format.
This is where I got stuck.